# g++ warnings, inline virtual function used but not defined

Tags: c++, g++

I'm currently having a problem with a [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) warnings I cannot get rid off. My code is working perfectly but this warning keeps poping up:

> ChildModel.h:136:24: warning: inline function virtual int ChildModel::getLinkCost(const Link&) const used but never defined [enabled by default]

I currently found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513230/how-to-get-rid-of-inline-function-used-but-never-defined-warning-in-g) on S.O, with the same problem, but the answer is specific to the library (defining something) so it doesn't work for me.

My code is as follow:

```
class Model {
public:
    virtual inline int getLinkCost(Link const& link) const;
};

class ChildModel: public Model {
public:
    /** Warning on the line bellow: **/
    virtual inline int getLinkCost(Link const& link) const;
};
```

The only function redefined by `ChildModel` is `Model::getLinkCost`, and the `Model::getLinkCost` method is only called by a method of `Model`. All the method are defined in a C++ file `Model.cpp`.

Comment: If it's `inline`, how is linking to the definition going to work?

Comment: `inline` here has no effect. Regarding the warning: it’s telling you that the function is *not* defined. So show us your `Model.cpp` (and how you compile/link your code).

Comment: "All the method are defined in a C++ file `Model.cpp`." - then it shouldn't be inline. Inline functions must be defined in every source file that uses them; so either remove the `inline` specifier, or define it in the header.

Comment: Inline virtual functions are difficult for the compiler to inline. I wouldn't bother with them in general.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ok, so I understand my mistake. But why is it working even with this warning? @NeilKir Now that you said it, I realized the uselessness of my `inline` in this case...

Comment: @Holt: It's probably "working" because it's only used directly (to populate the vtable) in the same translation unit as its definition. If you tried to call it non-virtually from a different unit, then you might get an error.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Okay so in other words (just to be sure I understood what you said) it's only works because I'm defining `ChildModel::getLinkCost` and `Model::getLinkCost` in `Model.cpp` and the only functions that used `Model::getLinkCost` is a method of `Model` also defined in `Model.cpp`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

> The definition of an inline function must be present in the translation unit where it is called.

If you are going to define the function in a .cpp file, you must remove the `inline` specifier from the .h file.